# Pebble Watch Faces

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm trying to create my own Pebble watch faces.  It appears no one has done this yet and there's no SDK.

So far I've figured out that the watch faces are hosted here:
http://pebble-static.s3.amazonaws.com/watchfaces/index.html

Each watch face is a .pbw file which is a zip file.  There's 3 files inside: app_resources.pbpack, manifest.json and pebble-app.bin.

The JSON file includes a list of all the parts of the watch face (images), which appears to be an app.  The .bin file is probably the executable binary and the .pbpack file is probably a bundle of all the resources.  I can't figure out how to extract the .pbpack file.  I'm also not sure what to do with .bin file.

I'm trying to post my progress here: http://hackingpebble.tumblr.com

Any thoughts on what to do with the .pback and .bin files?

Comment: These are my notes on the topic: [Watch Face Pebble Information](https://github.com/yepher/OSX-Pebble-Watch-Face-Creator/blob/master/PebbleInformation.md "Pebble Information")

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the Pebble SDK is now officially released.

Comment: @sarfata, the `[pebble-watch]` tag is used because the term "pebble" alone was ambiguous.

Comment: @Charles I beg to disagree. There are no other 'pebble' in the tech world and with the overlay popup we can make it perfectly not ambiguous. [pebble] looks and sounds a lot better than [pebble-watch] or [pebble-sdk]. Finally if we get pebble for everyone we can make pebble-watch, pebble-sdk and cloudpebble synonyms tags and kill those three.

Answer (score 15):

The SDK is now live. [developer.getpebble.com](http://developer.getpebble.com)

Answer (score 1):

I've begun looking at the .pbpack and the .bin in a hex editor and it's quite odd.  First with the .pbpack I've noticed a few patterns, in between each major chunks of bits, there is a bunch of 0's and then a 45 00 54, which I am guessing is acting like a delimiter.  I tried searching the file's hex signature to see if I would get lucky to find out that it was some obscure file format but got nothing.  Now with the .bin I figured I wouldn't get anywhere with the hex editing, however we do know what processor it is designed to run on (ARM Cortex-M3), which means we can reasonably assume that using a decompiler designed for arm processor files we can read it.  I'm researching into finding one, however it's a bit late at night for me to do too much more work, so I figured I'd give you what I have so far.

I know this is not a great response, but I figured maybe it'll help you with it what you're trying to do.

Comment: As my comment to the question, lets get in touch.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no Pebble company anymore, new community project [Rebble](https://rebble.io) took over.
It has [new SDK](https://developer.rebble.io/developer.pebble.com/sdk/index.html) on [Dev portal](https://developer.rebble.io/developer.pebble.com/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you guys might be looking toward something like [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com). This should give you some raw data.